# The value in the sharedpreferences is not getting updated in android app

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I am newbie in android and trying to use sharedpreferences to store data(String,int)

but the problem is whenever I try to update an existing key with a new value, the app crashes.

The app is supposed to add the names of people and the corresponding amount(an integer). If the name already exists in the sharedpreferences, the corresponding value should be updated with (**the old value + the new value**). I am trying to store the updated value.

I am unable to figure out the cause of the crash. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

The related files are as follows:

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    EditText etAmount;
    String name;
    int amount;                            
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);   
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);           
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add new person");
        View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.add_new_member_alert, (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content), false);
        // Set up the input
        final EditText etName = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etAmount = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.etAmount);       
        builder.setView(viewInflated);    
        // Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                name = etName.getText().toString();
                amount = Integer.parseInt(etAmount.getText().toString());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();    

                if (sharedpreferences.contains(name)) {
                    amount = amount + Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString(name, ""));
                    editor.putInt(name, amount);
                    editor.apply();
                }
                else{
                    editor.putInt(name, amount);
                    editor.commit();
                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name + " added!!" + "  Amount is " + amount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                dialog.dismiss();                       //work is done so dismiss
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();                        //cancel the operation
            }
        });    
        builder.show();            
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        });
    }    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }    
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

add_new_member_alert.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Name"/>           

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="Amount" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etAmount"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"/>                

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please attach the log and the exception stacktrace

Comment: Edit the question and add the stack-trace of crash from your logcat.

Comment: make separate key for set int in sharedpref, now you are putting int but you getting from getString() that will make error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be getting this error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>                                                                                          at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:205)

which due to this line

> amount = amount + Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString(name, ""));

so instead use this below one

> amount = amount + sharedpreferences.getInt(name, 0);

you are using putInt, so use getInt at retrieval time.

Comment: but my key is a String, so why should I use getInt() ?

Comment: your key is string , not a value that you are saving it.

You are using `editor.putInt(name, amount);` to save amount which is in int

Answer (score 0):

Change below line in your code.

```
amount = amount + Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString(name, ""));
```

to

```
amount = amount + Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString(name, "0"));
```

Comment: That line is inside `if (sharedpreferences.contains(name))` so changing second parameter wouldn't matter.